# Accessing chain position or multi-entity subchain in optaplanner?

Tags: optaplanner

We are using `Optaplanner` to come up with music playlists that follow a set of sound musical principles and rules  (with respect to key changes, etc):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iqya6xqc1jY

We’re using chained planning variables to avoid disrupting an otherwise solid “streak” of playlist tracks, but many of our rules involve some aspect of temporal reasoning across a subchain of X previous tracks. As an example,I’m trying to implement a rule that requires the key to change at least every five songs (to keep the playlist from getting too boring/monotonous).  What I’ve come up with works, but I’m wondering if there’s a less awkward way of doing it.

Here’s the rule as we have it right now, which I feel is ugly from a `DRY` and configurability perspective:

https://github.com/spotfire-io/spotfire-solver/blob/1c0fcda5256c337e214b33043a27fc25f615d0ef/src/main/resources/io/spotfire/solver/rules/rules.drl#L79-L88

```
rule "Should change key at least once every five songs"
    when
        $t0: RestPlaylistTrack(keyDistance == 0) // previousTrack is a chained variable
        $t1: RestPlaylistTrack(keyDistance == 0, previousTrack == $t0)
        $t2: RestPlaylistTrack(keyDistance == 0, previousTrack == $t1)
        $t3: RestPlaylistTrack(keyDistance == 0, previousTrack == $t3)
        $t4: RestPlaylistTrack(keyDistance == 0, previousTrack == $t3)
     then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 0, new BigDecimal(-2));
end
```

Another example would be implementing a rule that batches tracks of the same genre together (e.g. play 4 jazz tracks in a row followed by 4 rock tracks), or ensuring that we avoid playing the same artist 5 tracks from the last time we played that artist.

In this example, Is there a better way to keep track of the distance between two tracks and then specify a constraint on that? Some potential options we’ve considered include…

1. Provide a way to extract X-length sub-chains programmatically and apply the rules to that subchain.
2. Create a shadow variable that represents the position of the track relative to the anchor. Then we could create constraints like `RestPlaylistTrack(position < $t.position, position > $t.position - 5)` to apply to any tracks within 5 tracks of $t.
3. Using some sort of Drools aggregate expression that accumulates previous tracks via a map-reducey thing until reaching a certain maximum number of tracks.

The challenge we perceive with the first two solutions is that a chain swap move involves changes to three planning variables. If we have a chain that looks like `A <- B <- C <- D`, a swap between B and D involves a change to point D to A, B to C, and C to D. At the Drools or shadow variable level, I think there’s a risk doing a bunch of intermediate calculations before the move is complete. This might make score calculation pretty inefficient. For the third option, we’re just not sure how something like that would work mechanically.

If anyone (especially @geoffrey-de-smet) has examples on how this could be done, that would be greatly appreciated. If this is legitimately tricky in the current version of `Optaplanner`, we think adding a native position mechanism to chained planning modes would be super helpful as a future feature.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like consecutive shift constraints in nurse rostering. Detecting "no more than n shifts in a row" is non trivial in hand-written DRL. In nurse rostering, we use insertLogicals to deal with those, but I would recommend not to use that (it kills performance). I guesstimate that approach 1) (which gives up incremental calculation) is still faster than any insertLogical approach, unless you're queuing up thousands of songs.

In ConstraintStreams, approach 1 could maybe one day look like this:

```
constraintFactory.from(Shift.class)
    .groupBy(Shift::getEmployee,
             sort(Comparable.from(Shift::getStartDateTime, Shift::getId)) // BiConstraintStream<Employee, List<Shift>)) 
    .penalize((employee, sortedShiftList) -> ...); // One match for all bad subsequences of 1 employee
```

Approach 2) is interesting. Try it out and let us know if it works well enough for you.

Approach 3) is what I aim thinking of in ConstraintStreams at some point. This is incremental. Something like:

```
constraintFactory.from(Shift.class)
    .forEachSortedSubList(Shift::getEmployee,
             Comparable.from(Shift::getStartDateTime, Shift::getId,
             (employee, sortedShiftSubList) -> ...)
    .penalize(...); // One match per bad subsequence
```

If you have any suggestions on how you 'd like to use the API for approach 3) or how using it could look like, please put them on our google group discussion forum. It could help move the work along.

Comment: Thanks so much . I remember thinking I saw an approach like that *somewhere* in the examples but I was looking in vehicle routing. One possible difference with Nurse Rostering is that it doesn't seem to be using chained planning variables. I anticipate `Shift::getStartDateTime` or `Shift::getIndex` would be similar to the concept of `PlaylistTrack::getPosition` but the part we're struggling with is efficiently getting that value when the position updates on every move.

That being said, ConstraintStreams look amazing, especially if there's an easy way to sort by chain position.